# CS50x - Filter More

Tags: c, memory, filter, cs50, edge-detection

I doing filter of images bmp in c. The pset required the Sobel Operator. I don't know where I being mistake.

Help me please.

I'm basically making a copy of my image (because the original will be changed.)

Then I take the 3x3 values to put in the formula

So we add and multiply

Finally I take the result and put it in the formula: square root (Gx ^ 2 + Gy ^ 2)

If it exceeds 255 it must be 255, because RGB goes up to 255 which is white

And if there is a broken number, round to the nearest

```
// Detect edges
void edges(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    // Variáveis
    RGBTRIPLE temp[height][width];
    int GR[3][3];
    int GG[3][3];
    int GB[3][3];
    int Gx[3][3] = {{-1, 0, 1}, {-2, 0, 2}, {-1, 0, 1}};
    int Gy[3][3] = {{-1, -2, -1}, {0, 0, 0}, {1, 2, 1}};
    float resultR, resultG, resultB;

    // Cópia temporária do original
    for (int tempi = 0; tempi < height; tempi++)
    {
        for (int tempj = 0; tempj < width; tempj++)
        {
            temp[tempi][tempj].rgbtRed = image[tempi][tempj].rgbtRed;
            temp[tempi][tempj].rgbtGreen = image[tempi][tempj].rgbtGreen;
            temp[tempi][tempj].rgbtBlue = image[tempi][tempj].rgbtBlue;
        }
    }


    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {

            int countx = 0;

            // Pegar 3X3
            for (int x = i - 1; x < i + 2; x++)
            {
                int county = 0;
                for (int y = j - 1; y < j + 2; y++)
                {
                    if ((x < 0 || y < 0) || (x >= height || y >= width))
                    {
                        GR[countx][county] = 0;
                        GG[countx][county] = 0;
                        GB[countx][county] = 0;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        GR[countx][county] = temp[x][y].rgbtRed;
                        GG[countx][county] = temp[x][y].rgbtGreen;
                        GB[countx][county] = temp[x][y].rgbtBlue;
                    }

                    county++;

                }
                countx++;
            }

            float sumxR = 0, sumyR = 0, sumxG = 0, sumyG = 0, sumxB = 0, sumyB = 0;
            for (int ix = 0; ix <= 2; ix++)
            {
                for (int iy = 0; iy <= 2; iy++)
                {
                    sumxR = sumxR + (GR[ix][iy] * Gx[ix][iy]);
                    sumxG = sumxG + (GG[ix][iy] * Gx[ix][iy]);
                    sumxB = sumxB + (GB[ix][iy] * Gx[ix][iy]);

                    sumyR = sumyR + (GR[ix][iy] * Gy[ix][iy]);
                    sumyG = sumyG + (GG[ix][iy] * Gy[ix][iy]);
                    sumyB = sumyB + (GB[ix][iy] * Gy[ix][iy]);
                }
            }


            resultR = sqrt(sumxR * sumxR) + sqrt(sumyR * sumyR);
            resultG = sqrt(sumxG * sumxG) + sqrt(sumyG * sumyG);
            resultB = sqrt(sumxB * sumxB) + sqrt(sumyB * sumyB);

            if (resultR > 255)
            {
                resultR = 255;
            }
            if (resultG > 255)
            {
                resultG = 255;
            }
            if (resultB > 255)
            {
                resultB = 255;
            }

            image[i][j].rgbtRed = round(resultR);
            image[i][j].rgbtGreen = round(resultG);
            image[i][j].rgbtBlue = round(resultB);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is wrong?  Does it crash, is the result wildly wrong, just at the edges, or what?

Comment: @WeatherVane Apparently it works, but the cs50 has a check50 line command that tests all possibilities and says it is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change`sqrt(sumxR * sumxR) + sqrt(sumyR * sumyR)` to `sqrt((sumxR * sumxR) + (sumyR * sumyR))` and they are not the same

Comment: u r  welcome, next time give more clarity about your problem,see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example